# Why is my MSE not changing when the model trains

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, unet-neural-network

I'm currently working on a denoising algorithm with U-Net, and when I train it on my data, the MSE is not decreasing.

This is the shape of the images I am working with:

```
x_train_noisy.shape: (288, 256, 256, 3)
x_train.shape: (288, 256, 256, 3)
x_val_noisy.shape: (32, 256, 256, 3)
x_val.shape: (32, 256, 256, 3)
```

This is my neural network:

```
def unet(input_shape):


    #Encoder
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)  # Define input tensor with the given shape
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inputs)  # Convolutional layer 1
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)  # Convolutional layer 2
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)  # Max pooling layer 1

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool1)  # Convolutional layer 3
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2)  # Convolutional layer 4
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)  # Max pooling layer 2

    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool2)  # Convolutional layer 5
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv3)  # Convolutional layer 6
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)  # Max pooling layer 3

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool3)  # Convolutional layer 7
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv4)  # Convolutional layer 8
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)  # Dropout layer
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)  # Max pooling layer 4

    # Bottom
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(pool4)  # Convolutional layer 9
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv5)  # Convolutional layer 10
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)  # Dropout layer

    #Decoder
    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(
    UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(drop5))  # Upsampling and convolutional layer 11
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4, up6], axis=3)  # Concatenate the features from the contracting and expansive paths
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge6)  # Convolutional layer 12
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv6)  # Convolutional layer 13

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(
    UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6))  # Upsampling and convolutional layer 14
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3, up7], axis=3)  # Concatenate the features from the contracting and expansive paths
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge7)  # Convolutional layer 15
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv7)  # Convolutional layer 16

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(
    UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7))  # Upsampling and convolutional layer 17
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2, up8], axis=3)  # Concatenate the features from the contracting and expansive paths
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge8)  # Convolutional layer 18
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv8)  # Convolutional layer 19

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(
    UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8))  # Upsampling and convolutional layer 20
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1, up9], axis=3)  # Concatenate the features from the contracting and expansive paths
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(merge9)  # Convolutional layer 21
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)  # Convolutional layer 22

    # Output layer
    outputs = Conv2D(3, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(conv9)  # Assuming RGB images

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)  # Create the model with input and output layers

    return model  # Return the U-Net model
```

When I train the neural network:

```
input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]
model = unet(input_shape)

learning_rate = 0.001
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = learning_rate)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse'])

t0 = time.time()
u_history = model.fit(x_train_noisy, x_train, batch_size=32, epochs=100, validation_data=(x_val_noisy, x_val))
t1 = time.time()
training_time_in_seconds = t1-t0
print(f"U-Net training time: {training_time_in_seconds} seconds")
```

The mse is not changing:

```
Epoch 1/100
9/9 [==============================] - 77s 2s/step - loss: 0.0334 - mse: 0.0334 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 2/100
9/9 [==============================] - 20s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 3/100
9/9 [==============================] - 21s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 4/100
9/9 [==============================] - 21s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 5/100
9/9 [==============================] - 21s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 6/100
9/9 [==============================] - 21s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 7/100
9/9 [==============================] - 21s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 8/100
9/9 [==============================] - 21s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 9/100
9/9 [==============================] - 21s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 10/100
9/9 [==============================] - 21s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 11/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 12/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 13/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 14/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 15/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 16/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 3s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 17/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 18/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 19/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 20/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 21/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 22/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 23/100
9/9 [==============================] - 23s 3s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 24/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 25/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 26/100
9/9 [==============================] - 23s 3s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
Epoch 27/100
9/9 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 0.0167 - mse: 0.0167 - val_loss: 0.0211 - val_mse: 0.0211
```

I've decreased the learning rate to 0.0001 but that did not help either.

Comment: Do you know if an MSE of less than 0.0167 is possible? It may be that it learns a very simple denoising method very quickly, and there is no denoising method better than that one.